# Laravel collection - finding the key of value matching a condition

Tags: php, laravel

Take the following example of array manipulation with the Illuminate\Support\Collection class provided by the Laravel Framework.

```
$value = $arr->firstWhere('age', '>', 18);
$key = $arr->search($value, true);
```

In this code example, php must traverse the array twice. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a closure to the `search` method.

```
$key = $arr->search(function ($item, $key) {
    return $item['age'] > 18;
});
```

With arrow function (PHP >= 7.4.0)

```
$key = $arr->search(fn ($item, $key) => $item['age'] > 18);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-search